# What is wrong with ending a question with ありがとうございます?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

When I post a question and write ありがとうございます at the end of the question, other users complain about it or delete it.  What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In English, it is common to end a question with “Thank you.”  However, in Japanese, it is uncommon and odd to say ありがとうございます in a question.  A common phrase in Japanese to express thanks for a help in advance is よろしくお願いします.  (Remember, translation between two languages is rarely one to one!)

In the Stack Exchange network, [including “Thank you” in questions is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).  So the best way is probably to include none of “Thank you,” “ありがとうございます,” or “よろしくお願いします” in a question.

Comment: Considering that this answer relates to actual language usage... voting offtopic... move to JLU!

Comment: @jkerian: I thought of posting this on the main site, but I decided to post it here on meta because the answer contains the description specific to the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I was joking about the vote, since nearly everything gets moved in the other direction. But you do see ありがとうございます at the end of japanese-questions in forums all over the internet, and considering the normal explanation of that phrase in past/present ("ありがとうございました" for things people have done; "ありがとうございます" for things they are doing/about to do), it's a mistake that's easy to make.

Comment: @jkerian: I knew that you were joking about voting offtopic.  Sorry if my comment suggested otherwise.  I just wanted to explain the reason I chose to post this on meta.